# how to import rows that contain the same value more than once to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten

I have a list of sessions, I want to be able to import the ones that have been rescheduled (along with the new rescheduled session) to another sheet. So under colC one will say 'Rescheduled' and the other will say 'Attended'. So what I'd like to do is grab the participant name, but only if it shows up more than once, so I'd get both the rescheduled session and the new session. I tried using importrange and query, but couldn't quite get it right. How can I do this?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10ZWcO9DeBx6KjiyvFvcoBlGk7yw2b8z2gFPi26orOGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: and this will go to another spreadsheet or another sheet/tab?

Comment: also, you mention "I'd get both the rescheduled session and the new session" how is the "new session" labeled all we see are just 3 labels Rescheduled, Attended & Canceled

Comment: edit your sheet and include example of desired result

Comment: they would go to a different spreadsheet. the new session would be labeled as attended, which is why i can't just search for 'Rescheduled' and 'Attended' sessions because it would also show sessions that weren't rescheduled. in column F:H i show what i want to ultimately have, i want the rescheduled session and the new session that has been attended. so i was thinking a formula that would import rows that have duplicates in column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("10ZWcO9DeBx6KjiyvFvcoBlGk7yw2b8z2gFPi26orOGc", "Sheet1!A1:C"), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("10ZWcO9DeBx6KjiyvFvcoBlGk7yw2b8z2gFPi26orOGc", "Sheet1!A1:C")),,9^9))}, 
 "select max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3")), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Rescheduled|Attended'", )), 
 "where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null"), 
 "offset 1", )), 
 "(\d+/\d+/\d+) (.*) (Att.*|Res.*)"))
```

[image]

Formula Explanation:

- Take the IMPORTRANGE
- Merge all columns into one column
- Create a virtual array `{}`
- Pass into QUERY and pivot the data
- Transpose the result
- Use query to get only needed columns
- Transpose back
- Compare 1st and 2nd columns and remove
- Remove header row
- Flatten data into one column and split into the 3 needed columns

---

and if that's not enough:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SORT(TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("10ZWcO9DeBx6KjiyvFvcoBlGk7yw2b8z2gFPi26orOGc", "Sheet1!A1:C"), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("10ZWcO9DeBx6KjiyvFvcoBlGk7yw2b8z2gFPi26orOGc", "Sheet1!A1:C")),,9^9))}, 
 "select max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3")), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Rescheduled|Attended'", )), 
 "where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null"), 
 "offset 1", )), 
 "(\d+/\d+/\d+) (.*) (Att.*|Res.*)"), {
 "yyyymmdd\×m/d/yyyy", "@", "@"}), 2, 0, 1, 1), "^(\d+×)", ))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1axkWCO0GZLskyEPDARX6MDxhG7eiyBfPGsYBYpT-Wbk/edit#gid=0)

Comment: why do the dates not match? and can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @andie_6655321 yes, the month and date were swithched. fixed now

Comment: can you explain what's going on in the formula?

Comment: @andie_6655321 see explanation here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1axkWCO0GZLskyEPDARX6MDxhG7eiyBfPGsYBYpT-Wbk/edit#gid=0

Comment: if i wanted to query the import range to only include certain columns (this is using a different set of data, not what i originally shared) how would that go into the formula? i got it to work when i was completing it step by step, but could not figure out how to combine everything. this is what i want to put as the range of data: =query(IMPORTRANGE("1MbLjtyPlk9t1rANbRqof0U9eVh7t1qPw-IBKhOGVUoo", "Test_ET!A2:O"), "select Col11,Col3,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col1")

Comment: @andie_6655321 its hard to tell like this without closer examination where it fails. my guess lies within the query selection - those columns are probably in the wrong order but its all just speculation